# How can I get child component names as they or after they initialize in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, application-lifecycle

I've been studying Angular's [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) while looking for a way to know when and which child components are loaded.

I see that `ngAfterViewInit()`

> "Responds after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views."

Since ngAfterViewInit knows about the children, how could I get their identifying information as they (or after) they initialize?

Something like this pseudo code:

```
// ngAfterViewInit() - Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(‘Children should be loaded');
        // loop through ngAfterViewInit
        querySelector('body').classList.add(ngAfterViewInit[i].componentName);
    }
}
```

**sidenote:** the goal is to add component names or selector names to `<body>`'s class list.

Comment: What's this? identifying information

Comment: As far as I know, in order to have components communicate with each other, you want to use `@Output` properties.  When the child component initializes, you can broadcast an event that the parent component is subscribed to.

Comment: But considering what you are trying to do, I wonder if you could name your child components and refer to them straight in your markup.

Could you provide some code snippets of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey @JakeSmith Thats where I started, but it turns out that the lifecycle hooks do that without using `@input` and `@output`. I'd rather not setup I/O on every component in my app just to get the names if I don't have to. (I'll update the question with some psuedo code)

Comment: Gotcha.  I think I could help better if I knew a little more of what your code looked like.  If the components are not dynamically loaded in, you should be able to do something like `<app-my-child-component #myChild></app-my-child-component>` and then on your body tag: `<body class="{{myChild.coolProperty}}">...</body>`

Comment: Oh wow, like if each component class had a method that simply returned it's name as a string and trigger it in the body? Do I understand that right? It would be 1 step better than I/O setup but maybe we can get it cleaner still?